# JUnit Testing - assertTrue not throwing Exception

Tags: unit-testing, exception, assert, junit4

This is my first JUnit test and I don't understand why is not throwing an `AssertionError`, what am I doing wrong??

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;

public class MyFirstJUnitTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(MyFirstJUnitTest.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleAdd() {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 3;

        int c = a + b; //8

        Assert.assertTrue(c == 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [run JUnit from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line) you need to call the main method.

```
JUnitCore.main("MyFirstJUnitTest");
```

You are not supposed to use `JUnitCore` unless you need to access the result in a programmatic way, for instance if you are writing a JUnit plugin for an IDE:

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(MyFirstJUnitTest.class).getFailures();
```

`JUnitCore` catches any exceptions and stores them in the `Result`, which is a class that your JUnit plugin will read.

Comment: `getFailures()` does the job! Still, this is not how it is described in the basic JUnit cookbook: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm ... Do you recommend running tests from the command line?

Comment: Personally, I like the [JUnit plugin for Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128/what-gui-should-i-run-with-junitsimilar-to-nunit-gui) because it gives great graphical output.  Most Java IDEs should have a JUnit plugin if you are using an IDE.  Otherwise, I would just run tests from the command line unless you want to format your own output or create your own JUnit GUI.

Answer (score 1):

`AssertionError` is in this case caught by test runner.

Normally, `AssertionError`s are thrown by failing assertions made with `assert` keyword. This:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 3;

    int c = a + b; //8

    assert c == 7;
}
```

throws an `AssertionError` as expected, when running with assertion checks enabled.

Comment: Let me try to understand.. Isn't `assert` a Java keyword that is totally independent from the JUnit framework?? Also, your code above (with assert) does not throw an exception with me... :/

Comment: Yes, assert is a Java keyword independent from the JUnit. How are you running my code? Did you pass `-ea` argument to the JVM?

Comment: JUnit assertions also throw AssertionErrors, but those errors are caught by JUnit framework classes. As others said, JUnit allows access to failures in a different way, and normally you simply look if tests passed or failed in your IDE.

Comment: Nope, I run it from my IDE, I was just following the basic instructions in the JUnit cookbook: http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm What does `-ea` do?

Comment: It enables assertion checks created with `assert` keyword. Without this switch, they are not run.

Answer (score -1):

Assertions are not for throwing exceptions but for checking if your condition is correct. So this will show you, that something went wrong (in your JUnit-view in your IDE) but not throw any exceptions.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans, do you know where's the 'JUnit-view'? By the way, in JUnit4.10 javadoc there is the following about the assertTrue(boolean condition) function: `If it isn't (true) it throws an AssertionError without a message.`

Comment: Yes, but the AssertionError is what should be displayed in your JUnit-View. [Here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/junit-intro.html) is a tutorial for JUnit in NetBeans. Should help you to find the right view :)

Comment: NB: It is correct that no exception is thrown. It is a subclass of `java.lang.Error` that is thrown.

Comment: Who is downvoting without comment? Why?