# Is there a GUI for running JUnit/Selenium tests

Tags: user-interface, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I have some Selenium tests written in Java and run as JUnit tests. I run them from Jenkins, but now client would like to have access to them and run them individually.

Is there a standalone application for running JUnit tests that would enlist all the tests and allow users to create their own suites?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What GUI should I run with JUnit(similar to NUnit gui)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59128/what-gui-should-i-run-with-junitsimilar-to-nunit-gui)

Comment: I saw that comment, but since it didn't have the answer I needed, and it was posted 2 years ago, I asked this question. Also, I'm mostly interested in Selenium tests, so if anyone has some Selenium tool that I could use, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Try Eclipse. You just need to add the Junit and Selenium jars.

Comment: I need this tool for clients, and I think Eclipse is overly complicated for them. I was thinking of some tool that would have the list of tests, you select several tests, click run and get results.

Answer (score 0):

My team has written an application in JavaFX that we run our Selenium WebDriver scripts through.  We're currently working on putting it on a webpage for other users to access and run. We are pointing the tests to the Grid server on a virtual machine which sends them to clients on several other virtual machines (so many users can use it at once if needed).